# Need help solving hydrogen atom Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom with Mathematica 10.0. I use the following code:

```
NDSolve[{D[R[r],{r,2}]-2 Z^2/(2n^2) R[r]+2 Z/r R[r]-l(l+1)/r^2 R[r]==0,R[0]==Sqrt[2],R'[0]==-Sqrt[2]},R,{r,0,1}]
```

but I always get an error 1/0 encountered; if I solve between `{r,10^-10,1}`, I get a solution but it is wrong. The initial conditions come from my old quantum mechanics book which says that the radial solution for `Z=1`, `n=1` is `R[r]=Sqrt[2]*Exp[-r]`

Comment: What's the value of `l`?

Comment: @xzczd I forgot that `l=0`

Comment: Something is wrong with your equation. The given solution doesn't satisfy it: `D[R[r], {r, 2}] - 2 Z^2/(2 n^2) R[r] + 2 Z/r R[r] - l (l + 1)/r^2 R[r] == 0 /. 
     R -> Function[r, Sqrt[2]*Exp[-r]] /. n -> 1 /. l -> 0 /. Z -> 1 // Simplify`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
but I always get an error 1/0 encountered
```

This is because there is singularity at $r=0$. Just look at your ODE

```
ode = D[R[r], {r, 2}] - 2 Z^2/(2 n^2) R[r] + 2 Z/r R[r] - l (l + 1)/r^2 R[r] == 0
ic = {R[0] == Sqrt[2], R'[0] == -Sqrt[2]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And you are giving initial conditions at $r=0$.

In addition, you are using numerical solver and did not give any numerical values to `l` and `Z` and `n`, so I am not sure how you expected `NDSolve` to work (side note, do not use `l` as variable name, it looks like `1`.

```
l = 0; Z = 1; n=1;
ode = D[R[r], {r, 2}] - 2 Z^2/(2 n^2) R[r] + 2 Z/r R[r] - l (l + 1)/r^2 R[r] == 0
ic = {R[0] == Sqrt[2], R'[0] == -Sqrt[2]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 NDSolve[{ode, ic}, R, {r, 0, 1}]
 (*NDSolve::ndnum Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at r == 0.*)
```

One way is to push ic a little to the right of zero and hope for the best (there are better ways to find the starting point)

```
l = 1; Z = 1; n = 1;
eps = 1/10^6;
ode = D[R[r], {r, 2}] - 2 Z^2/(2 n^2) R[r] + 2 Z/r R[r] - l (l + 1)/r^2 R[r] == 0
ic = {R[eps] == Sqrt[2], R'[eps] == -Sqrt[2]};
NDSolve[{ode, ic}, R, {r, eps, 1}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[Evaluate[R[r] /. sol], {r, 0.0001, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you could solve it analytically

```
l = 0; Z = 1; n = 1;
ode = D[R[r], {r, 2}] - 2 Z^2/(2 n^2) R[r] + 2 Z/r R[r] - l (l + 1)/r^2 R[r] == 0;
eps = 1/10^6;
ic = {R[eps] == Sqrt[2], R'[eps] == -Sqrt[2]};
DSolve[{ode, ic}, R[r], r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**BUT**

It seems your ODE is wrong. I looked it up at [this site](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/327/hatom.php) and it looks like you are solving the radial equation

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So using the above, the solution now very close to what your book says it is supposed to be `Sqrt[2]*Exp[-r]`. Used `n=2` here which gave better approximation. It is possible also the solution `Sqrt[2]*Exp[-r]` is meant to be good approximation for small $r$ only, that is why it agrees well with numerical solution in the plot for small $r$.

```
l = 0; Z = 1; n = 2;
En = -Z^2/n^2;
ode = D[ R[r], {r, 2}] + 2/r R'[r] + (2 (En + Z/r) - l (l + 1)/r^2) R[r] == 0
eps = 10^(-6);
ic = {R[eps] == Sqrt[2], R'[eps] == -Sqrt[2]};
sol = NDSolve[{ode, ic}, R, {r, eps, 1},  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{Sqrt[2]*Exp[-r], Evaluate[R[r] /. sol]}, {r, 0.0001, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May be it is best to post exact ODE to solve as it is shown in book so one does not have to guess.